# Kohana 3.1 Autoload not working (on a different machine)

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, autoload

I'm facing a rather weird problem.
In one of my Kohana Modules Autoload seems to fail for just a single class, and also only on my staging box, but not on my development box.
Also, it loads all other classes just fine in the same piece of code.

So i have this class in which i call other classes:

```
class PayPal_AdaptivePayment extends PayPal {
    public function DoAdaptivePayment($params)
    {
        $receiverList = new PayPal_Container_ReceiverList();
        ....some more other code
        $result = new Paypal_Result_AdaptiveResult($response);
    }
}
```

Both Classes PayPal_Container_ReceiverList() and Paypal_Result_AdaptiveResult() are located in folders on the level of the class i'm calling them in.

```
PayPal_Container_ReceiverList() lives in ./Container/receiverlist.php

Paypal_Result_AdaptiveResult() lives in ./Result/adaptiveversult.php
```

sofor some reason, it can't find the PayPal_Container_ReceiverList class unless i include it specifically at the top
but it can find the Paypal_Result_AdaptiveResult() class.

There's nothing really crazy going on in the class that isn't working:

```
class PayPal_Container_ReceiverList extends PayPal {

    public $receiver = array();


    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

that's it.

The PayPal_Result_AdaptiveResult class is a bit more complex, and i don't think it'd make sense pasting it here.

Giving the fact that this works on one box but not the other might give me an indication that it could have to do with php instead of kohana, but i'm not sure.

on the box it works i have php 5.3.8
on the one where it doesn't i have php 5.3.2

Does anyone see anything obivous here which i'm just not seeing?

any help is greatly appreciated!

T.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in one of the filenames (adaptiveversult.php). Also all the folders and files should be lowercase. Perhaps the system it's working on is Windows (which is case-insensitive). Basically this is the path where the classes should be:

PayPal_Container_ReceiverList in `paypal/container/receiverlist.php`

Paypal_Result_AdaptiveResult in `paypal/result/adaptiveresult.php`

Comment: ah, sorry i made that typo when putting in this post.

i'm not on windows, i got osx. i also did have it in lowercase before i think, lemme try this again, even though i don't think thats it.